# Swift lengthOfBytes for emoji

Tags: swift, unicode, emoji

The following code:

```
func printLengthOf(_ str: String) {
    print("String: \(str)")
    print("UTF8: \(str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf8))")
    print("UTF16: \(str.lengthOfBytes(using: .utf16))")
}

let emoji1 = ""
let emoji2 = ""

printLengthOf(emoji1)
printLengthOf(emoji2)
```

Shows:

```
String: 
UTF8: 4
UTF16: 4
String: 
UTF8: 8
UTF16: 8
```

However, Android count the same emoji as 2 bytes, I thought the number of bytes for the same emoji should not be platform-dependent. Is there anything I did wrong?

Thanks!

Update:

Android uses below code to compute length:

```
*byteLength = myString.getBytes("UTF-8").length;*
```

Comment: Bytes vs code units?

Comment: Android would show the exact same results for the same character encodings.

Comment: **_Android count the same emoji as 2 bytes_** Then your android code counting bytes may be wrong, or you have counted some other thing. Please show your Android code showing _2 bytes_.

Comment: You'll want to output the actual bytes on Android to see what the error is.  is encoded in UTF-8 as f09f 918d f09f 8fbf. Even  can't be encoded in 2 bytes (it's f09f 918d). Your Android code is incorrect or your `myString` is not what you think it is. You can take the output from Android and plug it into this site to see what character you're really looking at: https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder